# Is the "meta-description" tag required when "meta-robots" is set to noindex?

Tags: seo, noindex, meta-description

I am using `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` for few pages that are not supposed to be displayed in any search results.

I know how important is the `meta`-`description` tag for SEO.

Is it still required for pages that are not indexed?

Comment: It is neither correct or wrong, but usage would be pointless. The meta description is for giving users a description in search results, but when using no-index that page will not appear in the results, hence pointless.

Comment: That looks obvious, so no penalty hanging for not using it ?

Comment: no, Google and other search engines only consider indexable pages.

Comment: Also, meta description is not important for SEO. Google doesn't consider description for ranking. It only helps in user CTR. Anyway, it's pointless to have desc in your case.

Comment: Yes you're right. But in some way, user CTR impacts ranking, it's kind of SEO, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no use to put meta descriptions tag on noindex pages